# What are living and nonliving things?

Tags: word-meaning

In the sentence

> "An ecosystem consists of the **living** and nonliving **things** in an area that interact with one another"

what does *living things* mean? Does the human being fall into this category of "living things"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is in danger of being put on hold as general reference - can you please explain what resources you have consulted, and why they don't make the difference clear to you?

Comment: Do you remember a lesson in Biology? http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Living_thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we do belong to the category of living things, any animal and plant also does, I think the sentence refers to the habitat that surrounds us, for instance we [LIVING THINGS] interact with buildings and trains [NON-LIVING THINGS]

Hope this helps :)